"Backend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on"
I am new in debugging so when I try to run my file with Debugging mode it shows me a warning "Backend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on." and breakpoint doesn't work properly. I am not sure how to solve this problem.
I have checked the boot file "Debug Kernel Data Structure" and shows the following configuration.
"ONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_COMPRESSED is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4 is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5 is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y
CONFIG_PAHOLE_HAS_SPLIT_BTF=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF_MODULES=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=1024
# CONFIG_STRIP_ASM_SYMS is not set
# CONFIG_READABLE_ASM is not set
# CONFIG_HEADERS_INSTALL is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH is not set
CONFIG_SECTION_MISMATCH_WARN_ONLY=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FORCE_FUNCTION_ALIGN_64B is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_FRAME_POINTERS=y
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y
CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FORCE_WEAK_PER_CPU is not set
# end of Compile-time checks and compiler options

#
# Generic Kernel Debugging Instruments
#
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_DEFAULT_ENABLE=0x01b6
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL_SEQUENCE=""
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FS_ALLOW_ALL=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FS_DISALLOW_MOUNT is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FS_ALLOW_NONE is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_HONOUR_BLOCKLIST=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_KGDB_TESTS is not set
CONFIG_KGDB_LOW_LEVEL_TRAP=y
CONFIG_KGDB_KDB=y
CONFIG_KDB_DEFAULT_ENABLE=0x1
CONFIG_KDB_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_KDB_CONTINUE_CATASTROPHIC=0
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_EARLY_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_UBSAN_SANITIZE_ALL=y
CONFIG_UBSAN=y
# CONFIG_UBSAN_TRAP is not set
CONFIG_CC_HAS_UBSAN_BOUNDS=y
CONFIG_UBSAN_BOUNDS=y
CONFIG_UBSAN_ONLY_BOUNDS=y
CONFIG_UBSAN_SHIFT=y
# CONFIG_UBSAN_DIV_ZERO is not set
CONFIG_UBSAN_BOOL=y
CONFIG_UBSAN_ENUM=y
# CONFIG_UBSAN_ALIGNMENT is not set
CONFIG_UBSAN_SANITIZE_ALL=y
# CONFIG_TEST_UBSAN is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KCSAN=y
# end of Generic Kernel Debugging Instruments

CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_MISC=y

#
# Memory Debugging
#
# CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC is not set
# CONFIG_PAGE_OWNER is not set
CONFIG_PAGE_POISONING=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGE_REF is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA_TEST is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_DEBUG_WX=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_WX=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_PTDUMP=y
CONFIG_PTDUMP_CORE=y
# CONFIG_PTDUMP_DEBUGFS is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_OBJECTS is not set
# CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG_ON is not set
# CONFIG_SLUB_STATS is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE is not set
CONFIG_SCHED_STACK_END_CHECK=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_DEBUG_VM_PGTABLE=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_VM is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_VM_PGTABLE is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_DEBUG_VIRTUAL=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_VIRTUAL is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_MEMORY_INIT is not set
CONFIG_MEMORY_NOTIFIER_ERROR_INJECT=m
# CONFIG_DEBUG_PER_CPU_MAPS is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KASAN=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KASAN_VMALLOC=y
CONFIG_CC_HAS_KASAN_GENERIC=y
CONFIG_CC_HAS_WORKING_NOSANITIZE_ADDRESS=y
# CONFIG_KASAN is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KFENCE=y
CONFIG_KFENCE=y
CONFIG_KFENCE_SAMPLE_INTERVAL=0
CONFIG_KFENCE_NUM_OBJECTS=255
# CONFIG_KFENCE_STATIC_KEYS is not set
CONFIG_KFENCE_STRESS_TEST_FAULTS=0
# end of Memory Debugging

# CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ is not set

#
# Debug Oops, Lockups and Hangs
#
# CONFIG_PANIC_ON_OOPS is not set
CONFIG_PANIC_ON_OOPS_VALUE=0
CONFIG_PANIC_TIMEOUT=0
CONFIG_LOCKUP_DETECTOR=y
CONFIG_SOFTLOCKUP_DETECTOR=y
# CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_SOFTLOCKUP_PANIC is not set
CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_SOFTLOCKUP_PANIC_VALUE=0
CONFIG_HARDLOCKUP_DETECTOR_PERF=y
CONFIG_HARDLOCKUP_CHECK_TIMESTAMP=y
CONFIG_HARDLOCKUP_DETECTOR=y
# CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HARDLOCKUP_PANIC is not set
CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HARDLOCKUP_PANIC_VALUE=0
CONFIG_DETECT_HUNG_TASK=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_HUNG_TASK_TIMEOUT=120
# CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HUNG_TASK_PANIC is not set
CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HUNG_TASK_PANIC_VALUE=0
# CONFIG_WQ_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_TEST_LOCKUP is not set
# end of Debug Oops, Lockups and Hangs

#
# Scheduler Debugging
#
CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SCHED_INFO=y
CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS=y
# end of Scheduler Debugging

# CONFIG_DEBUG_TIMEKEEPING is not set

#
# Lock Debugging (spinlocks, mutexes, etc...)
#
CONFIG_LOCK_DEBUGGING_SUPPORT=y
# CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING is not set
# CONFIG_LOCK_STAT is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_RT_MUTEXES is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SPINLOCK is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_WW_MUTEX_SLOWPATH is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_RWSEMS is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_ATOMIC_SLEEP is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCKING_API_SELFTESTS is not set
# CONFIG_LOCK_TORTURE_TEST is not set
# CONFIG_WW_MUTEX_SELFTEST is not set
# CONFIG_SCF_TORTURE_TEST is not set
# CONFIG_CSD_LOCK_WAIT_DEBUG is not set
# end of Lock Debugging (spinlocks, mutexes, etc...)

# CONFIG_DEBUG_IRQFLAGS is not set
CONFIG_STACKTRACE=y
# CONFIG_WARN_ALL_UNSEEDED_RANDOM is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_KOBJECT is not set

#
# Debug kernel data structures
#
# CONFIG_DEBUG_LIST is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_PLIST is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SG is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_NOTIFIERS is not set
# CONFIG_BUG_ON_DATA_CORRUPTION is not set
# end of Debug kernel data structures

# CONFIG_DEBUG_CREDENTIALS is not set

I think debug is not set up. Do I have to set up this to run python file with debugging mode?

Hi, if you encountered this warning when using matplotlib package, you can modify #interactive: False  to #interactive: True in your matplotlibrc file.

Are you using matplotlib  package and setting QtAgg backend in your code like this?
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('QtAgg')

xxx 

If so, please try to modify #interactive: False to #interactive: True.
1.Please navigate to your python packages installed  folder and find the matplotlib  package.
For example:
C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python version\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib

2.Navigate to mpl-data folder and open matplotlibrc file.
3.Modify interactive to True.

